# map datatype in aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-cli

i am trying to add a message to queue in amazon aws sqs

so i tried this

```
root~#  aws sqs send-message --queue-url "queue/url" --message-body "message with attribute" --message-attributes '{"Name": "somename", "Type":"String", "Value":"somevalue"}'
```

bit it gives me this error

```
'unicode' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

but if i remove the `--message-attributes` part from the command

```
 root~#  aws sqs send-message --queue-url "queue/url" --message-body "message with attribute"
```

then it works perfect

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sqs/send-message.html

i guess that it is map type how can send this parameter in map format

`--message-attributes (map)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass `--message-attributes (map)` data structre like `{attr1 : {"DataType":"type1.option", "StringValue":val1}, attr2 : {"DataType":"typ2.option", "StringValue":val2}, ...}`

So your example becomes as follows:

## sending queue

```
$ aws sqs send-message --queue-url "queue/url"  --message-body "message with attribute" --message-attributes '{"somename" : { "DataType":"String", "StringValue":"somevalue"}}'
{
    "MD5OfMessageBody": "ZZZZ",
    "MD5OfMessageAttributes": "YYYY",
    "MessageId": "06524772-XXXX"
}
```

## receiving queue

```
$ aws sqs receive-message --queue-url "queue/url" --message-attribute-names somename
{
    "Messages": [
        {
            "Body": "message with attribute",
            "ReceiptHandle": "dummy==",
            "MD5OfBody": "ZZZZ",
            "MD5OfMessageAttributes": "YYYYS",
            "MessageId": "06524772-XXXX",
            "MessageAttributes": {
                "somename": {
                    "DataType": "String",
                    "StringValue": "somevalue"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```